# ALTER COLUMN query taking too much time

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005. I have a table tblTest that has a column called DisplayValue. Current data type and length is NVARCHAR(1000). We are trying to change the size of the column using below query -

```
BEGIN TRAN
ALTER TABLE [schema Name].[tblTest]
ALTER COLUMN DisplayValue NVARCHAR(4000)
-- COMMIT
-- ROLLBACK
```

But when I execute this query it is going to in process but doesn't get completed. I have waited for 40 minutes but still in progress. I have tried several times but no luck. Can someone please help me.

There is only 2540 records in the table. There is no uncommited transaction.

Comment: Are you in a production system? Or local? In production system with long time execution your table can be locked by other operation, so you can't change its column size.

Comment: Is the table / DB in use by other applications? If so, may be a locking issue. EDIT: bugger, too late ^^

Comment: Hi Joe, I am working in development environment. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I have checked with our DBA. But he is saying he doesn't see any locking issue.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: Hi Mels, yes you are right. there was a locking. I don't know how my DBA missed that for the first time. We have killed that then the ALTER COLUMN query worked fine. Thank you very much. You can post your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same query in my machine. It's working fine for me.

Restart the Sql server services and then execute that code.
Or
Try to change it through query design using ssms tool.